# Detecting file type for file upload through AJAX in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, rest

I am having trouble detecting the file type of files when I try to upload them using jQuery ajax ,

Here is how I upload a file  using jQuery:

```
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', $('#file')[0].files[0]); //my file input

    //Header require for the framework I am using
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
             'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
       }
    });
    $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        url: window.location.origin+'/'+'dataset/create/'+project.pid,
        data:formData,
        processData:false,//needs to be false for else jQuery gives illegal invocation
        contentType:false,  
        mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
        success: function (data) {

            uploadDataCallback(data);

        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.error('Error:', data);
        }
    });
```

Here is how I handle I try to figure out the file type in php ,

```
        // Check MIME Type .
        $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

        //var_dump($finfo->file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])); //THIS IS ALWAYS 'text/plain'
        if (false === $ext = array_search(
            $finfo->file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']),
            array(
                'csv' => 'text/csv',
                'json' => 'application/json',
                'csv' =>'text/plain',

            ),
            true
        )) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid file format.');
        }
```

$finfo always gives 'text/plain' for any type of file i.e. csv ,json etc. I want to detect when user uploads a json file or a csv file so I can parse them appropriately

Here is the entire function for reference:

```
 function create($pid){

        $tmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $file = file($tmpName);

        //uploading a file
        try {

            // Undefined | Multiple Files | $_FILES Corruption Attack
            // If this request falls under any of them, treat it invalid.
           if(!isset($_FILES['file']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'][0])){
                throw new Exception('File missing');
            }

            if (
                !isset($_FILES['file']['error']) ||
                is_array($_FILES['file']['error'])
            ) {
                throw new Exception('Invalid parameters.');
            }

            // Check $_FILES['file']['error'] value.
            switch ($_FILES['file']['error']) {
                case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
                    break;
                case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                    throw new Exception('No file sent.');
                case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
                case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                    throw new Exception('Exceeded filesize limit.');
                default:
                    throw new Exception('Unknown errors.');
            }

            //check filesize here. 
            if ($_FILES['file']['size'] > 1000000) {
                throw new Exception('Exceeded filesize limit.');
            }

            ///////////////THIS IS WHERE IS ALWAYS SAYS 'text/plain' EVEN IF IT IS A JSON FILE
            // Check MIME Type .
            $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

            //var_dump($finfo->file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])); //this is always text/plain
            if (false === $ext = array_search(
                $finfo->file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']),
                array(
                    'csv' => 'text/csv',
                    'json' => 'application/json',
                    'csv' =>'text/plain',

                ),
                true
            )) {
                throw new Exception('Invalid file format.');
            }

            //  name it uniquely.

            //  obtain safe unique name from its binary data.
            $path=sha1_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);



            //dev config
            if (!move_uploaded_file(
                $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
                sprintf(base_path().'/public/devStorage/%s.%s',
                    $path,
                    $ext
                )
            )) {
                throw new Exception('Failed to move uploaded file.');
            }

            if($ext=='csv'){

                $csvAsArray = array_map('str_getcsv', $file);
                //dd($csvAsArray);
                $rows=count($csvAsArray);
                //everything fine,file is uploaded succesfully
                //save dataset
                $dataset=new DataSet;   
                $dataset->name=$_FILES['csv']['name'];
                $dataset->iduser=Auth::user()->iduser;
                $dataset->pid=$pid;
                $dataset->path=$path;
                $dataset->type=$ext;
                $dataset->rows=$rows;
                $dataset->cols=count($csvAsArray[0]);
                $dataset->save();


                for($i=0;$i<count($csvAsArray[0]);$i++ ){
                    $datasetCol=new DataSetColumn;
                    $datasetCol->col_name=$csvAsArray[0][$i];  //first row is assume to be the header row
                    if(is_numeric($csvAsArray[1][$i])){        //second row is taken as value and its type is assumed for entire column
                        $datasetCol->col_type='Number'; 
                    }
                    else{
                        $datasetCol->col_type='String';
                    }
                    $datasetCol->iddata_sets=$dataset->iddata_sets;

                    $datasetCol->save();
                }

                return json_encode($dataset);
            }
            else if($ext=='json'){
                dd('jsonff');
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $message='Error:'.$e->getMessage();
            return $message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does `file($_FILES['file']['type'])` return?

Comment: Where is the error ? For all we know this code works just fine you never said what is wrong !

Comment: Sorry about that , I wanted to detect the file type in php ,I use finfo for that which doesn't seem to work apparently , I have edited the question